WordPress Migration
I'm working on two Websites which is running on WordPress(built on Wordpress).
One is Production and One is Development.
I'm trying to move Complete production site to Development.... But failed.
I moved the Copied wp-content folder and replaced the wp-content on development site.
and it's running, But When I see content, Images, and sections it's totally different.
I need explanation for this. Why this is happening?

Could it be caching?

The wp-content folder only includes plugin, theme, media etc. files. The actual content, e.g. pages and posts, is stored in the database. If you haven't copied the database from production to development, then the dev site keeps showing whatever content it happens to contain.
